# Angular or React Not recompiling on save

Tags: angular, create-react-app, macos-catalina

When I create a new Angular/React Project and edit some files and save them Angular/React does not recompile.

I am using macOS Catalina. Have anybody faced the same problem?

When I google I see the same problem occurring in a Ubuntu Machine and the solution is to update the file `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` with some higher value. Does Any such solution exists for macOs Catalina too?

Comment: Are you running `npm start` when you make this changes? That’s the only time it would automatically recompile your dev code and refresh the page.

Comment: Yes I would run `npm start` and leave it running and then when I make a change I don't see automatic recompilation happening.

Comment: I am able to make this work with angular by adding `--poll=2000` to the `ng serve` command. Is there any such alternative for create-react-app